# Proving $A \sim B \iff (\exists k\in \mathbb{N}^+)(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+)nk\in A \iff nk\in B$ is equivalence relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation, relations, equivalence-relations

In an exercise I'm asked to prove that (not whether, the prompt assumes it is true)
$$For \ A,B \subseteq \mathbb{N}\ \ A \sim B \iff (\exists k\in \mathbb{N}^+)(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+)nk\in A \iff nk\in B$$ is an equivalence relation. I have no problem proving reflexivity and symmetricity but my issue is the transitive property.

Isn't it true that:
$\{2,4,8\} \sim \{2,3,4,8,9\} \land \{2,3,4,8,9\} \sim \{ 3,9\}  $ but
$\{2,4,8\} \nsim \{ 3,9\}$? This would suggest this isn't an equivalence relation since it fails transitivity.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: And $\sim$ is supposed to be a binary relation *where*?

Comment: $\{2,4,8\} \sim \{3,9\}$, because you can take $k = 100$ say. Any two finite sets are $\sim$ by the same reasoning.

Comment: Another way of phrasing it is $A \sim B \iff \exists k : A \cap k \mathbb N = B \cap k \mathbb N$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Ahh, ok. Makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @SeanEberhard do you know how I would prove it is transitive?

Comment: Indeed, and I edited it as an answer, so that we can delete our comments. But what is the difference between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N^+$ in your post? Is it that $0$ is excluded from $\Bbb N^+$? if so, don't you want to exclude it also from $A,B$?

Comment: @AnneBauval I've copied it exactly from the sheet I got given by my professor. I also don't get the point of only using positive naturals when defining k and n, it might be a clerical error.

Comment: Requiring $k\ne0$ is reasonable (otherwise most sets are $\sim$)

Answer (score 0):

We must check that it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Reflexivity follows immediately since $nk \in A \iff nk \in A$.

Symmetry follows since $nk \in A \iff nk \in B$ is equivalent to $nk \in B \iff nk \in A$.

For transitivity, say $A \sim B$ and $B \sim C$. Then there exists $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}^+$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $nk_1 \in A \iff nk_1 \in B$. Similarly $\exists k_2 \in \mathbb{N}^+$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $nk_2 \in B \iff nk_2 \in C$.

Now consider $k_1k_2 \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. $nk_1k_2=(nk_2)k_1 \in A \iff (nk_2)k_1=nk_1k_2 \in B$ since $A \sim B$. But also $nk_1k_2=(nk_1)k_2 \in B \iff (nk_1)k_2=nk_1k_2 \in C$ since $B \sim C$. Thus $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $nk_1k_2 \in A \iff nk_1k_2 \in C$, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

As @SeanEberhard commented:

- any two finite sets are $∼$, since
- $A \sim B \iff (\exists k\in \mathbb{N}^+)(A \cap k \mathbb N^+= B \cap k \mathbb N^+).$

Let us now concentrate on transitivity, since (not surprisingly) you `have no problem proving reflexivity and symmetr[icit]y'.

My (now deleted) comment was:

> note that if $A∩k\Bbb N^+=B∩k\Bbb N^+$
> then $A∩k′\Bbb N^+=B∩k′\Bbb N^+$
> for every multiple $k′$
> of $k$.

Indeed, since $k'\Bbb N^+\subset k\Bbb N^+$: $A∩k'\Bbb N^+=A∩(k\Bbb N^+∩k'\Bbb N^+)=(A∩k\Bbb N^+)∩k'\Bbb N^+$, and similarly for $B$.

In your (now deleted) reply, you understood correctly how it led to the solution:

> if $A∼B$ with $ k = k_1$ and $B∼C$ with $k = k_2$ then $A∼C$ for $k= k_1k_2$.

(instead of $k_1k_2$, you can even use *any* common multiple of $k_1$ and $k_2$, for instance the least one).

That's all.